# Drawing Area turned white

Tags: adobe-illustrator, drawing, white

The drawing area in illustrator turned white -- I do not mean the art board. How do I change it back to gray?

Comment: This is tech support and off topic -- however.... Overprint Preview

Answer (score 2):

Go to View -> Overprint View. I think you just changed your view settings.